# How to replace all single characters except the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I need to replace all single characters except the first.
Because I working with the server that I programmed in Python.
The information I passing always on Url.
The Url is:

```
http://localhost:8100/index2?decode=demo_title=Demo+title&proc1_script=script.sh+parameters&inputp3_id=pepepe&outputp2_value=&demo_input_description=hola+mundo&outputp4_visible=on&inputdata1_max_pixels=1024000&inputdata1_image_depth=1x8i&tag=&outputp1_id=nanana&proc1_src_compresion=zip&outputp3_description=&inputp1_type=text&inputdata1_description=input+data+description&inputp2_description=bien%3F&inputp3_description=funciona&outputp3_type=header&outputp2_visible=on&outputp3_visible=on&outputp1_type=header&outputp3_value=&demo_params_description=va+bien&demo_result_description=win%3F&outputp1_description=&inputdata1_type=image2d&inputp1_value=si&proc1_chk_script=off&outputp4_info=&outputp2_id=nanfdsvfa&inputp1_description=funciona&demo_wait_description=boh&outputp4_description=&inputp2_id=papapa&inputdata1_id=id_lsd&inputp1_visible=on&proc1_chk_cmake=off&proc1_cmake=-D+CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3Astring%3DRelease+&inputp3_visible=+off&outputp1_visible=on&outputp1_value=&outputp4_value=&inputp2_visible=on&proc1_source=lsd-1.5.zip&inputp3_value=si&proc1_make=-j4+-C+&images_config_file=cfgmydemo.cfg&outputp2_type=header&proc1_subdir=xxx-1.5&proc1_chk_make=on&inputp1_id=popopo&proc1_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipol.im%2Fpub%2Falgo%2F...&inputp2_value=no&demo_data_filename=data_saved.cfg&inputdata1_info=info_lsd&outputp3_info=&inputdata1_image_format=.pgm&inputdata1_compress=False&outputp1_info=&outputp3_id=nananartrtrt&inputp2_type=integer&proc1_id=lsd&inputp3_type=float&outputp2_description=&outputp4_type=header&outputp2_info=&outputp4_id=nana&tag=&inputp4_id=popopo&inputp4_type=text&inputp4_description=cddc&inputp4_value=sdlk&inputp4_info=dsl
```

Now I have this problem that the first character is important on URL and not have to replace.

This is my script for replace all characters in Javascript:

```
var $fm = $("#formparam");
                $.get($fm.attr('${nextstep}'))
                    .done(function(data, ok){
                    var fr=$fm.serialize();
                    fr=fr.replace(/\&/g,"+%23+");
                    fr=fr.replace(/\=/g,"%24+");
                    alert('call done: ' +fr);
                    // data is the content of the response
                    document.location.href+="index2?"+fr})
                    .fail(function(data){
                    alert('call failed');
                    // call failed for some reason -- add error messaging?
                    });
```

And How to change the script for not replace the first = ?

Update:

I want to change all single caracters = and not the first.

EXAMPLE

Before

```
some=string=here=more_people
```

After

```
some=string_here_more_people
```

Comment: Write your own replace function. I think it's not difficult to do.

Comment: @haitaka If you think that this answer's question is not difficult..
Why I write this question?

Comment: debes usar "why" en vez de "because" ;)

Comment: Exactly!!!! @Evan Now I correct...

Comment: jaja sabia que eras espanol cuando te vi usar esa palabra xD ... vale, me voy - buena suerte con la pregunta!

Comment: En verdad Evan... Yo soy Italiano que fui en España en Erasmus (un año)...

Comment: ahhh vale vale, mi culpo, perdona eh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27039/discussion-between-mirko-cianfarani-and-evan)

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani mira a mi ultima repuesta. He inluido un ejemplo que funciona perfectamente :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
function replacew(str,pattern,value){
    int index=str.search(pattern);
    return str.substr(0,index+1)+str.substr(index+1).replace(pattern,value);
}
```

Comment: Pattern and value that are?
Pattern= "=" and value?
I did not understand

Comment: pattern is string you search for and value is string that takes the place of pattern. For instance fr.replace(/\&/g,"+%23+"); in your code, pattern is /\&/g and value is +%23+

Comment: Excuse me but your wine this question

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/EarUc/5/

Start with some string (empieza con alguna `string`)

```
var str1 = "=moo=kie=";
```

Call the function: (llame la funcion)

```
alert(replaceButFirst(str1, "="));
```

Include the following code to use: (incluya el codigo siguiente para usarlo)

```
function replaceButFirst(strOriginal, strToReplace){

var n=strOriginal.indexOf(strToReplace);
var firstPart = strOriginal.substring(0, n + 1);
    var tempString = strOriginal.substring(n + 1);
tempString = tempString.replaceAll(strToReplace, "");

return firstPart + tempString;

}
```

Original use of the function can be found [here](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg8#msg8)

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) 
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
}
```